# Angular Nested Item In Router Link

Tags: routes, nested, angular6, json-server

I have this JSON file containing jobs like:

```
{
  "jobs": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Web Dev",
      "price": 200,
      "subtypes": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Client Side",
          "price": 49.99
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Server Side",
          "price": 49.99
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "SEO",
          "price": 49.99
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

My routes are like:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'menu', component: MenuComponent },
  { path: 'menu/:id', component: JobDetailComponent },
  { path: 'menu/:id/:subtypes/:id', component: ItemDetailComponent }
]
```

The menu is displaying all jobs correctly from this code:

```
    <div fxFlex *ngIf="jobs">
      <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="200px" >
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let job of jobs" [routerLink]="['/menu', job.id]">
          <h1>{{job.name | uppercase}}</h1>
        </mat-grid-tile>
      </mat-grid-list>
    </div>
```

On clicking the 'mat-grid-tile' the code is correctly routing to the job subtypes page as follows:

```
  <div fxFlex *ngIf="job.subtypes">
    <div *ngFor="let stp of job.subtypes" [routerLink]="['/menu', stp.id, '/subtypes', stp.id]">
        <h1>{{stp.name}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

However I cannot get the router link to redirect to the desired subtypes page on click.

The subtypes page is as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="job.subtypes">

  <h1>
    {{job.name}}
  <h1>
</div>
```

And it's not displaying the desired info on the clicked subtype link

Besides my code being incorrect, as i presume it is; is the fact that am using nested info an issue with the JSON-serve api am using to test my dev app

Comment: In short I want this kind of navigation:
menu => jobs => jobs' subtypes => show detailed info.

On my browser window I want this displayed as follows:
localhost:4200/menu/0/1, so as to show detailed info abt the 'server-side' subtype eg. You may correct this comment as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Child Routes. 
Angular documentation - https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component
And good example here: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/routing/child_routes

Note - it means the child routes will be accessible only from the parent (e.g. only from /menu/...)

Comment: Thanx for a prompt response, but will you try and show it using my code above